# What's wrong with binding onclick event like this?

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with binding onclick event like this?? Somehow the function never gets triggered.

[image]

I think more elaborate codes will explain the question better, I was using es6 template to generate the above codes sippet:

```
let tmp = ` <div id="pageAppointment">
        ${this.renderDates(this.data.dateOptions)}
        ${this.renderTimes(this.timeOptions)}
        ${this.data.tip ? `<div class="tip flex align-center">${this.data.tip}</div>` : ``}
        <div class="btn-wrap mui-flex">
            <div class="ok-btn cell" onclick="${this.onOK}">OK</div>
        </div>
    </div>`
$(this.root).html(tmp);
```

Comment: you need to execute it, not just declare

Comment: There are some good answers below.  I would also recommend that you explore attaching event handlers in script rather than doing so in attributes.

Comment: Just as a side note - please do not post code as an image

Comment: The `this.onOK` method is being converted to a string. It's basically `this.onOK.toString()`. That's why you're getting the function syntax.

Comment: how would I do it the right way? but still using this es6 template syntax?

Comment: `this.onOK` is a function, right? Then bind it via `addEventListener` or the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: @Blake: The issue is going to be that the variable scope of the function you're binding in the attribute is the global scope, and the value of `this` will be the element itself. *(Technically the scope is a little more complicated, but that's not likely relevant here.)* So whatever `this` is referencing won't be available to your handler the way it's currently bound unless `this` is the element itself or is available as a global variable.

Comment: @squint actually `this` is the global one, this.onOK returns the correct function, but just as said above, this function had been convert string.

Answer (score 3):

Because `onclick="function name();"` creates a function, it doesn't call it. You can do 
`onclick="alert(111);"` instead.

```html
<button onclick="alert(111);"> click </button>
```

Or call the function which is in a .js file like :

```js
function onOK(){
  alert(111);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onOK();">click</button>
```

It is really bad, but as an example, you can do :

```html
 <button onclick="function onOK(){
                    alert(111);
                   }; onOK();" >click</button>
```

which creates the function THEN call it. It is an example, don't do that but now you understand how it works

Answer (score 3):

Your handler just defines a function `onOK`, but you never call it so why should it be called? If you want it to be executed turn it into an IIFE like so

```
(function onOK() { ...})()
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be:

```html
<div onclick="alert(111);">ok</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onclick function on your script file, then append on your elements.

```
<div onclick="someFunc()">ok</div>
```

Script file:

```
function someFunc(){

     ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your function in the end `function name();`

```
<button onclick = "function clck(){alert('hi');}clck();">
Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```js
function myFunction(){
  alert('Clicked');
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myFunction()">Button Div</div>
```